# Problem on Maximum Modulus Principle (Solution Verification)

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Newman, Bak chapter 6, q12

> Suppose $f$ and $g$ are both analytic in a compact domain D. show that $\lvert f(z) \rvert + \lvert g(z) \rvert$ takes its maximum on the boundary. [Hint: Consider $f(z) \exp 
> (i \alpha) + g(z) \exp(i \beta)$ for appropriate $\alpha$, $\beta$]

My solution:

$\forall z, \, \exists \alpha, \, \beta$ s.t. $\lvert f(z) \exp(i \alpha) + g(z) \exp(i \beta) \rvert = \lvert f(z) \rvert + \lvert g(z) \rvert$ ... (1)

$\forall z, \, \alpha, \, \beta$, $\lvert f(z) \exp(i \alpha) + g(z) \exp(i \beta) \rvert \leq \lvert f(z) \rvert + \lvert g(z) \rvert$ ... (2)

Consider $z_0 \in D$. From (1), $\exists \alpha_0 \, , \beta_0$ st $$ \begin{aligned} \lvert f(z_0) \rvert + \lvert g(z_0) \rvert &= \lvert f(z_0) \exp(i \alpha_0) + g(z_0) \exp(i \beta_0) \rvert \\ &\leq \lvert f(z_1) \exp(i \alpha_0) + g(z_1) \exp(i \beta_0) \rvert  \, \text{by maximum modulus principle applied to}\, f(z) \exp(i \alpha_0) + g(z) \exp(i \beta_0), \text{for some}\, z_1 \in \, bdry(D)  \\ &\leq  \lvert f(z_1) \rvert + \lvert g(z_1) \rvert \, \text{from (2)}\end{aligned}$$

(Also, by continuity, maximum of $\lvert f\rvert + \lvert g\rvert$ is attained on D)

Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Hello! This seems ok so far, but you've not really concluded. So you've shown $|f(z_0)|+|g(z_0)|\le|f(z_1)|+|g(z_1)|$ for some $z_1\in\partial D$ but this $z_1$ is actually dependent on the $z_0$ sadly (because it arose as the maximum of a function involving $\alpha_0,\beta_0$), so it's not sufficient yet.

Comment: MathJax tip: `\partial` is the symbol for partial derivatives but also for boundary. You can also do this: `\mathrm{bd}` or something similar to render $\operatorname{bd}(D)$

Comment: Apologies, my answer had a big flaw in it but it’s corrected now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd personally argue like this:

> Since $|f|+|g|$ is a continuous real valued function on a compact domain, we know that it must attain its maximum somewhere on $D$. We just need to show this "somewhere" is on the boundary of $D$. Suppose $|f|+|g|$ attained its maximum on the interior of $D$, at some $z_0$: fix $\alpha,\beta$, be such that $|f(z_0)|+|g(z_0)|=f(z_0)\exp(i\alpha)+g(z_0)\exp(i\beta)=:h(z_0)$. $h$ is holomorphic on $D$, and $|h|\le|f|+|g|$ always, so $h$ attains its maximum on the interior of $D$, at $z_0$ as well. Then by the maximum modulus principle is $h$ constant. Therefore, in either case, $|f|+|g|$ attains its maximum on the boundary of $D$ (and strictly *only* on the boundary if $h$ is non-constant).

Comment: "by the maximum modulus principle, if $|f|+|g|$ attained its maximum on the interior of $D$, $|f|+|g|$ would be a constant function". The usual version of the maximum modulus principle applies to the modulus of a holomorphic function and $|f|+|g|\neq |f+g|$ so it is not so easy to apply the max. mod. principle.

Comment: Apologies, thank you for catching the error. I believe it is fixed now @Pelota